# Redhat 8 rsyslog TLS collector taking over old log collector. Can I reuse certificate?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, certificate, syslog, rsyslog

I am building a redhat 8 rsyslog log collector to replace an old log collector and am required to set it up with TLS.  I am using the same public IP address and was hoping to reuse the same purchased certificate that was used previously.  Is it possible to reuse the same certificate for the TLS configurations?  I exported from the old server the public and private key as a PFX file.  I also have the original requested certificate from said certificate authority.  How do I go about doing this if possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should copy the key, the certificate and the root certificate chain. ALso you need to install `rsyslog-gnutls`. Then add the lines in the config (something like):

```
$DefaultNetstreamDriver gtls

$DefaultNetstreamDriverCAFile /etc/rsyslog-keys/ca.pem
$DefaultNetstreamDriverCertFile /etc/rsyslog-keys/node3-cert.pem
$DefaultNetstreamDriverKeyFile /etc/rsyslog-keys/node3-key.pem
```

You can check [this web page](https://www.golinuxcloud.com/secure-remote-logging-rsyslog-tls-certificate/) for more info.